# Why does my JavaFX application fail to run on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: python, java, iot

I have a problem starting application on rasberry pi 4.

To summ up what i know and what i tried.
Application has 2 parts, 1 is python application that starts the machine(real machine with senzors and all, from code looking it is made up as some kind of service and it is run on startup).
Second part is java application as .jar file. That works and it is run on rasberry pi 3.
On rasberry pi 3 setup is easy, there is image that is burned onto sd card, once it is mounted into rasberry pi 3 it automaticly starts python in back and java application in some kind of form on 7 inch display. Once machine is powered on, it starts everything automaticly.

The next problem is that we made switch from rasberry pi 3 to rasberry pi 4. We still load same image and rasberry boots itself. We run config file from python and we set up service on startup and it starts fine. Problem is that configuration does not automaticly start java application. On that card we have 2 files. Java program, python program and jdk-9-0-4 file. I tried entering java -version on cmd, it doesnt recognize that command. I installed java default kit with sudo command. But when i try to start the app i get error message : "Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application" and i cannot start it. I found that javafx is not supported anymore in newer java versions so i downloaded lib from "https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/" for my pi architecture. I tryed that on virtual box using "Raspberry Pi OS with desktop and recommended software" using Debian version: 11 (bullseye) that i downloaded from https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/operating-systems/ .

On virtualbox i managed to start the program using next command :"java --module-path "javafx-sdk-20.0.1 lib directory location" --add-modules javafx.control,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics -jar myapp.jar "

App gets started and shows all elements but it is not functional cause i cannot simmulate machine enviorment cause it connects trought vpn on database. That is great and i managed to start the app.

Problem is when i do all that configuration on rasberry pi 4, when i start java application in cmd,my rasbian pi for desktop os gets frozen and i have to manually shut it down.
To give more info:
- i use jdk 17 ( needed to use for javafx-sdk 20)
- i have only jar file of my java app and i cannot recompile it
- app runs on raspian pi 3 without desktop gui available
Things i did not try but am going to:
-install Raspberry Pi OS Lite
-install jdk 17
-will place javafx-sdk files onto my sd card along with java and python program
-connect all with machini and start it up to se what happens
Did any of you encounter does kind of a problem?
Did i go to much out of the box with those jdk17 and javafx-sdk-20 lib?
Is there possibility that i use that jdk9-0-4 and start that java program using that same jdk9-0-4 ?

To give more info:
- i use jdk 17 ( needed to use for javafx-sdk 20)
- i have only jar file of my java app and i cannot recompile it
- app runs on raspian pi 3 without desktop gui available
Things i did not try but am going to:
-install Raspberry Pi OS Lite
-install jdk 17
-will place javafx-sdk files onto my sd card along with java and python program
-connect all with machini and start it up to se what happens